# how to get send, receive byte and network bandwidth utilization

Tags: java, networking

Using `java.net.NetworkInterface` I am getting the status (up/down) of network.

I want to get the value of send and receive byte on the network card.
And I need to calculate network utilization also.

How to get these in Java?

Comment: Could you post what you have done so far and what it is that is not working as you expect?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a pure Java way of doing this.
So one solution is to use JNI and a native library, which of course would have to be OS-specific.

If you want something more portable, I suggest trying out [SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNMP). All common OS should support querying such data via SNMP (perhaps after installing an SNMP server), and there are also Java SNMP client implementations available.

Comment: SNMP is the correct answer.  This is an example in python: [How can I check the data transfer on a network interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731411/how-can-i-check-the-data-transfer-on-a-network-interface-in-python/7791143#7791143)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [OSHI](https://github.com/oshi/oshi#supported-features). The [`NetworkIF`](https://github.com/oshi/oshi/blob/30b0467efb4b63479e0d521abb0feccd4d829be9/oshi-core/src/main/java/oshi/hardware/NetworkIF.java) class supports everything you need.