# How can I check the data transfer on a network interface in python?

Tags: python, linux, networking, snmp, pysnmp

There is a socket method for getting the IP of a given network interface:

```
import socket
import fcntl
import struct

def get_ip_address(ifname):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(
        s.fileno(),
        0x8915,  # SIOCGIFADDR
        struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15])
    )[20:24])
```

Which returns the following:

```
>>> get_ip_address('lo')
'127.0.0.1'

>>> get_ip_address('eth0')
'38.113.228.130'
```

Is there a similar method to return the network transfer of that interface? I know I can read `/proc/net/dev` but I'd love a socket method.

Comment: 'network transfer'? Byte counts? network protocol? Wiring type?

Comment: A socket != network interface. If you mean that you want TX/RX bytes/packets, that's at the link level. You should be able get the info from the kernel via a NETLINK socket (which is how the `ip` command works), but it would be much easier to simply parse /proc/net/dev and get the same information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to poll ethernet interface statistics is through SNMP...

- It looks like you're using linux... if so, load up your `snmpd` with these options... after installing [`snmpd`](http://www.net-snmp.org/), in your **/etc/defaults/snmpd** (make sure the line with `SNMPDOPTS` looks like this):

  `SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -I -smux,usmConf,iquery,dlmod,diskio,lmSensors,hr_network,snmpEngine,system_mib,at,interface,ifTable,ipAddressTable,ifXTable,ip,cpu,tcpTable,udpTable,ipSystemStatsTable,ip,snmp_mib,tcp,icmp,udp,proc,memory,snmpNotifyTable,inetNetToMediaTable,ipSystemStatsTable,disk -Lsd -p /var/run/snmpd.pid'`
- You might also need to change the ro community to `public` <sup>See Note 1</sup> and set your listening interfaces in `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` (if not on the loopback)...
- Assuming you have a functional `snmpd`, at this point, you can poll `ifHCInBytes` and `ifHCOutBytes` <sup>See Note 2</sup> for your interface(s) in question using this...

**poll_bytes.py**:

```
from SNMP import v2Manager
import time

def poll_eth0(manager=None):
    # NOTE: 2nd arg to get_index should be a valid ifName value
    in_bytes = manager.get_index('ifHCInOctets', 'eth0')
    out_bytes = manager.get_index('ifHCOutOctets', 'eth0')
    return (time.time(), int(in_bytes), int(out_bytes))

# Prep an SNMP manager object...
mgr = v2Manager('localhost')
mgr.index('ifName')
stats = list()
# Insert condition below, instead of True...
while True:
    stats.append(poll_eth0(mgr))
    print poll_eth0(mgr)
    time.sleep(5)
```

**`SNMP.py`**:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import re

class v2Manager(object):
    def __init__(self, addr='127.0.0.1', community='public'):
        self.addr      = addr
        self.community = community
        self._index = dict()

    def bulkwalk(self, oid='ifName'):
        cmd = 'snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -Osq -c %s %s %s' % (self.community,
            self.addr, oid)
        po = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, executable='/bin/bash')
        output = po.communicate()[0]
        result = dict()
        for line in re.split(r'\r*\n', output):
            if line.strip()=="":
                continue
            idx, value = re.split(r'\s+', line, 1)
            idx = idx.replace(oid+".", '')
            result[idx] = value
        return result

    def bulkwalk_index(self, oid='ifOutOctets'):
        result = dict()
        if not (self._index==dict()):
            vals = self.bulkwalk(oid=oid)
            for key, val in vals.items():
                idx = self._index.get(key, None)
                if not (idx is None):
                    result[idx] = val
                else:
                    raise ValueError, "Could not find '%s' in the index (%s)" % self.index
        else:
            raise ValueError, "Call the index() method before calling bulkwalk_index()"
        return result

    def get_index(self, oid='ifOutOctets', index=''):
        # This method is horribly inefficient... improvement left as exercise for the reader...
        if index:
            return self.bulkwalk_index().get(index, "<unknown>")
        else:
            raise ValueError, "Please include an index to get"

    def index(self, oid='ifName'):
        self._index = self.bulkwalk(oid=oid)
```

**END NOTES:**

1. SNMP v2c uses clear-text authentication.  If you are worried about security / someone sniffing your traffic, change your community and restrict queries to your linux machine by source ip address.  The perfect world would be to modify the `SNMP.py` above to use SNMPv3 (which encrypts sensitive data); most people just use a non-public community and restrict snmp queries by source IP.
2. `ifHCInOctets` and `ifHCOutOctets` provide instantaneous values for the number of bytes transferred through the interface.  If you are looking for data transfer rate, of course there will be some additional math involved.

Comment: Incidentally, once you have `snmpd` running on your server, you can leverage the all the power of [cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) and [nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) in your server management endeavors

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using self.cmdGen all over the script. There are still places where cmdgen.CommandGenerator is re-created on each .get() and .walk() etc. call. That really hurts performance. Especially when you load up all MIBs.